# Android Image centered in design but not in application

Tags: center

I have problem. I am using android studio 2.2.3 
[image: image describing the problem]

That traffic light
And when I run app

[image: image describing the problem 2]

it is not centred as in design, why is this happening ?
my java and xml code

```
package com.example.filip.traficcontrol;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imageView =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        ImageButton imageButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        ImageButton imageButton3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        ImageButton imageButton4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);

        imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cetl);
            }
        });

        imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.zetl);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cetl);
                    }
                }, 3000);

            }
        });

        imageButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.zltl);
            }
        });

    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.filip.traficcontrol.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/code"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cetl"
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:keepScreenOn="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        tools:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want the picture of traffic light centered can someone help ?
Its just ff aplication not hacking application if someone thought.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out this way
I was cutting those traffic lights from image where were 3 of them. So I reworked graphics to make every trafficlight in middle of picture. Works for me fine